# Migration file  issue -"Project Not Exists"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn, msbuild

I have a Migration File .

```
cd F:\Manoj\Projects\Labtrack\eChecklist_Labinal\EngTrackingMigration
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild build.proj /t:Migrate
```

I have Updated the my SVN Folder . And Microsoft Visual Studio build is Successful .It is giving an error "Project File Not Exists " But I have given the correct path and project file exists .The database changes made are not reflected in my local  database . What is the reason for this . How to solve this .

Answer (score 2):

First, use the *Visual Studio Command Prompt* under `Microsoft Visual Studio 2008` > `Visual Studio Tools` > `Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt` so you don't have to state the full path of MSBuild and ensure environment variables are loaded.

Then validate the MSBuild input parameters:

```
MSBuild "F:\Manoj\Projects\Labtrack\eChecklist_Labinal\EngTrackingMigration\build.proj" /t:Migrate
```

if it still fails, you may turn on [logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), e.g.:

```
MSBuild "F:\Manoj\Projects\Labtrack\eChecklist_Labinal\EngTrackingMigration\build.proj" /t:Migrate /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=MyLog.log;append=true;verbosity=diagnostic
```